# Styling tables in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, fullcalendar

Hi I'm working with JQuery fullCalendar in Angularjs and need some help with some table styling. The fullcalendar uses it's own css file from the plugin that can be seen [here](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.css).

The problem is that in the project/website there are others stylesheets, among them a stylesheet created to make tables responsive. I can't control which stylesheets the HTML has access to. And this makes the calendar use an entirely other unlogical styling in small window size.

So is there any possible way to force the controller to look away from some stylesheets or style the calendar own stylesheet in such a way that it will be the controlling style?

Edit:
Forgot to say that the aforementioned stylesheet is styling tables in general without any classnames and since it's very much used throughout the website changing that into classes isn't really viable at this point.

I have narrowed it down to this css code in question that goes in and change the calendar in small window. Remove this entirely and the calendar is responsive and works great. The rest of the website not so much. But from my pov the css in the full calendar stylesheet from earlier should still have more specificity?

```
/* Make other tables responsive */
table:not([name='start_time']), thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
}
/* Make other tables responsive */

thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}

tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 50%!important;
    border: transparent!important;
}
```

Comment: You can override any CSS rule using more specific one http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/

Comment: You can override css rules by adding `!important` after specific rule, another way is to have stronger css selectors which is explained here https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Can you try adding the stylesheet which contains the required style at the last

Comment: @1l13v It is usually not recommended to use `!important` statement for any CSS property's value but could be the easiest fix, ya

Comment: Hmm but as I read those guides it should already use the more specific styling that's in the calendar.css as the other stylesheet is just styling tables in general.

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, but if you want to make sure only a certain(single) rule be applied it's the easiest fix. Using many `!important` it's not a good practice. But using complex css selector it's messy too and for large css files it could  make the browser render page a little bit slower

Comment: I have added the particular css code that is the problem for me from an external stylesheet. I still can't see how I can circumvent these without changing classes all over the website?

Answer (score 1):

To Do that create new scss or css file and copy main class for AngularJS Table and overwrite it , can be do like that : ( This is just example )

```css
.table {
  
  tr{
    Some attributes
    }
  
  th{
    Some attributes
    }
  
  }
```